# SQL: Find which column values (for all rows) in table1 are empty and mention all of them (for all rows) in table 2

Tags: sql, regex, validation, null, ssms

Given Table1 (input table) having 4 columns country, state, city, block.
Out of which, we only have to check Null or blank for 1st three columns

Table2 (error table) is Table1 + additional column (called RejectReason)
This Reject Reason should have all the column names which are blank or null for a particular row. Eg: "State, City column value is/are null or blank" (the order or written style is not important, only it should say that both these column values is null or blank.

Null or blank means value = NULL or '' or ' '

My actual work Table1 has 1 million plus records, around 15 columns (out of which 7 columns needed to be checked for Null or blank condition).
PS: I am working in SQL Server Management Studio, which is a part of a data validation procedure

So, what is the fastest way to do the work?

Table1 sample
[Table1 having 4 columns country, state, city, block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSEvs.png)

Table2 sample
[Table2, error table, has 4 + Reject Reason column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkWbT.png)

I tried doing this in two steps.

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT A.*,CAST('Mandatory field Blank or NULL: ' AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS 'RejectReason' FROM Table1 AS A 
WHERE Country IS NULL OR Country=''  OR Country=' ' OR
    State IS NULL OR State='' OR State=' ' OR 
    City IS NULL OR City='' OR City=' ' OR


UPDATE Table2
    SET RejectReason = CONCAT(RejectReason, 'Country ')
    WHERE RejectReason like '%Mandatory%' AND (Country IS NULL OR Country ='' OR Country =' ' )
UPDATE Table2
    SET RejectReason = CONCAT(RejectReason, 'State ')
    WHERE RejectReason like '%Mandatory%' AND  (State IS NULL OR State ='' OR State =' ')
UPDATE Table2
    SET RejectReason = CONCAT(RejectReason, 'City ')
    WHERE RejectReason like '%Mandatory%' AND (City IS NULL OR City ='' OR City =' ' )
```

This First check for each row, if there is null or blank. And then individually check, which column is null or blank (**doing the same thing twice**)
PS: RejectReason like '%Mandatory%' is written because other errored out rows in table2 have different RejectReason (they should not get, only the words like 'State City' concatenated to them, if the entire sentence that 'column is blank or null: state, city ' is concatenated then, it would be the best.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a case expression within `CONCAT_WS` function as the following:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT country, state, city,
   CONCAT_WS(' ',
     'Column Null Or Blank:',
     CASE WHEN country IS NULL OR country = '' THEN 'Country' END,
     CASE WHEN state IS NULL OR state = '' THEN 'State' END,
     CASE WHEN city IS NULL OR city = '' THEN 'City' END
   ) RejectReason
FROM table1
WHERE country IS NULL OR state IS NULL OR city IS NULL
 OR '' IN (country, state, city)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zMwisOwl).